# Enable Dygraphs custom plotter with zoom-in

Tags: dygraphs

I am using a custom plotter to calculate a specific Bezier curve for each connecting line.
This works pretty well, but it takes a few seconds for my dataset (about 4K points).

However, with that much data on a graph, the Bezier curves don't add much until the graph is zoomed in. (Say about 20 points on the graph)

What I'd like to do is to enable the custom plotter only when there are 20 points on the graph. Otherwise, use the default plotter.

I've been looking at some options, but they all hinge on figuring out how many points are currently displayed on the graph. What's the best way to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did it the simple way:
inside the custom plotter I do something like:

```
if(e.points.length <20) {
  // draw curves
}
else {
  Dygraph.Plotters.linePlotter(e);
}
```